# Can't get math c++ program to work

Tags: c++

So i am trying to make one of my first very simple math programs in c++. the problem is that 
i can't seem to get the function potodds to do what i want. There is no problem in getting it to multiple the two variables `(x,y)` that works perfectly fine. the problem occurs when i try to replace return `x*y*100` with return `(x/y)*100`. in this case it always return the value 0?

Hopes that someone out there can help me pinpoint my mistake.

The code looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int x;
int y;
int potodds(int x, int y) {
   return x * y * 100; //(x/y)*100;
}
int main() {
   using namespace std;

   cout << "what's the size of the pot?" << endl;
   cin >> y;

   cout << "what's the size of the bet?" << endl;
   cin >> x;

   cout << "your potodds are:" << endl;
   cout << potodds(x, y) << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

---

Thanks to Ebyrob i got the solution.

the problem that I was having was that I was trying to divide an integer, that was assigned a decimal value and by definition an integer can only contain whole numbers. The result was that the integer was rounded down to zero.

Comment: change `int` to `double`.  You're seeing truncation on `int` divide.

Comment: Or change the order, like `100 * x / y`.

Comment: @FredLarson Yes, assuming this is a good time to tackle the complexities of operator precedence and order of execution.  Also that rounding isn't more appropriate than truncation...

Comment: @ebyrob: I don't know that it's any worse than tackling the complexities of floating point. My solution still truncates, but comes a lot closer than always zero. It's the best you can do for an integer solution.

Comment: @FredLarson You're entitled to your opinion but integer arithmetic **can** round.  (Fixed-point for instance)  `int r = 1000 * x / y; r += r % 10 >= 5 ? 10 : 0; r /= 10;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x and y are defined as integral values. The integral division returns only the quotient. So if x is less than y then x /y will be equal to 0.

So it would be better to substitute expression `( x /y ) * 100` for `( 100 * x ) / y`

Otherwise use float numbers

For example

```
( double )x / y * 100
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're trying to divide by `y`, not `100`.

Comment: `x / y * 100.0` also gives 0 for x < y. Because of associativity, `x / y` is still an integer subexpression.

Comment: Just remember that `float` = `double` for useful applications of `float`.  (Basically `float` is too "small" to hold most interesting data values with any kind of accuracy)

Comment: @Fred Larson  Oh you are right.:)

Answer (score 0):

Changing int to double should solve the problem but also "using namespace std;" is always outside of main when I program. I don't know if this affects anything but you might consider putting it above your main function because it might be causing a problem now or it might cause a problem in another program you make. I think it is a matter of it being global or private but I would have it outside of main so that any other functions you use can use it ( assuming I'm right ).

Answer (score 0):

If you divide two integers, the result will be an integer (the quotient: the remainder is discarded).

So, `1 / 2 -> 0` instead of `0.5`.

Note also that `(1 / 2) * 100` is therefore `0 * 100 -> 0`, while, as Vlad says,
`100*1/2 -> 100/2 -> 50`, which is what you want.